Switch Protection
I am using SPDT and multiplexer switches in my design and these switches are directly connected to Px connectors for various channels. Transducers (capacitive load below 500 Ω) are connected at Pin 2 and 4 of each of these Px connectors. The switches are working at +/- 5 V supply. The problem is that these switches are getting burnt up and I believe the reason is the high voltage spikes coming from the transducers.
So, thinking of putting these TVS diodes AQ1205-01FTG in parallel with the lines going to the switches, but not sure if it would help?
Tried to put as much information as I could here, but if anything missing I can add it up.


What kind of transients are present (impedance, amplitude, waveform)? What is the expected working range? Can you afford any resistance between connector and switch?

You could protect the inputs with TVS diodes, do this if you expect voltages larger than the voltage of the switches from the transducer, or if the external lines are facing cables that can be touched by humans. Then it would be a good idea to protect them.
